# Handling variable process iterations with some probability of failure

Tags: probability

Suppose we are given a process with success probability $p$ and need to complete $n$ iterations of the process that take time $t$ each. If the process fails, we need to redo all processes since the last checkpoint was made. Suppose further that the time cost of making a checkpoint is $c$ and they are made at regular intervals of $m \le n$ across the $n$ iterations.

How should we choose $m$ so as to minimize the expected overall execution time to complete the $n$ iterations?

I got stuck at calculating the expected value when we go back and redo, say $k\ge2$, processes. I got the summation $E[process_2] = tp + E[process_1]\sum_{i=0}i((i+1)tp)^i(1-p)^{i^i}$ for the expected time to complete $2$ processes going back to the first process at failure, which I'm not entirely confident in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected time $\tau$ to get from one checkpoint to the next satisfies

$$
\tau=p^mmt+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}p^k(1-p)\left((k+1)t+\tau\right)=p^mmt+\frac{mp^{m+1}-(m+1)p^m+1}{1-p}t+\left(1-p^m\right)\tau\;,
$$

and thus

$$
\tau=-\frac{1-p^{-m}}{1-p}t\;.
$$

Assuming $m\mid n$, that makes the total cost

$$
\frac nm\left(c-\frac{1-p^{-m}}{1-p}t\right)\;.
$$

Setting the derivative with respect to $m$ to $0$ yields a transcendental equation for $m$ that you'd need to solve to in order to optimize with respect to $m$.